# Strange format-list behavior in this PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a weird behavior with format-list. When I paste the following code directly into the shell - everything works like a charm:

```
    @("Administrator","SomeUser","SomeOtherUser") |% {
        $uname = $_;
        $u = gwmi win32_useraccount |? { $_.Name –eq $uname }
        if (-not $u) {
            write-host ("[-] "+ $uname + " does not exist!")
        } else {
            write-host ("[+] "+ $uname + ":")
            $u
        }
    }

    @("Administrator","SomeUser","SomeOtherUser") |% {
        $uname = $_;
        gwmi win32_groupuser -computer . | select GroupComponent,PartComponent |? { $_.PartComponent -match ",Name=`""+$uname+"`""} | fl *
    }
```

However, when I put the same code in a function, say test, and call test, PowerShell drops an error about format-list. I cannot figure out why - maybe I have been searching on the wrong end, but I did not find anything.

```
    function test {
        @("Administrator","SomeUser","SomeOtherUser") |% {
            $uname = $_;
            $u = gwmi win32_useraccount |? { $_.Name –eq $uname }
            if (-not $u) {
                write-host ("[-] "+ $uname + " does not exist!")
            } else {
                write-host ("[+] "+ $uname + ":")
                $u
            }
        }

        @("Administrator","SomeUser","SomeOtherUser") |% {
            $uname = $_;
            gwmi win32_groupuser -computer . | select GroupComponent,PartComponent |? { $_.PartComponent -match ",Name=`""+$uname+"`""} | fl *
        }
    }
```

The error message displayed is:

> out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by  
>   a user-specified "format-list" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.  
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], InvalidOperationException  
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

A screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A function is supposed to return one or more Objects, not formatted output data (which is intended for the host/screen).

In other words, **don't use Format-* cmdlets inside a function**

Simply remove `|fl *` from the last statement, and pipe the *output* of the `test` function call to `Format-List` instead:

```
function test {
    @("Administrator","SomeUser","SomeOtherUser") |% {
        $uname = $_;
        $u = gwmi win32_useraccount |? { $_.Name –eq $uname }
        if (-not $u) {
            write-host ("[-] "+ $uname + " does not exist!")
        } else {
            write-host ("[+] "+ $uname + ":")
            $u
        }
    }

    @("Administrator","SomeUser","SomeOtherUser") |% {
        $uname = $_;
        gwmi win32_groupuser -computer . | select GroupComponent,PartComponent |? { $_.PartComponent -match ",Name=`""+$uname+"`""}
    }
}

test |fl *
```

Along the same lines, at least for writing reuseable functions:

- Don't use [Write-Host in your functions - it's bad](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)
- Use full cmdlet names instead of aliases (like `%`, `select`, `gwmi`)

You might also benefit from using the `-Query` parameter with `Get-WmiObject`, and have WMI do the filtering instead of returning all users to powershell and *then* filtering them

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Name = '$uname'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot - PLUS thank you for the style comments. I admit my script is rather quick and dirty plus i don't script PowerShell that often.

Comment: You're most welcome :-) A verbose style is *especially* handy when it's to be maintained by people who don't look at PowerShell regularly