# Format-List in Powershell-Function not working

Tags: powershell

i want to use format-list inside a function in a powershell script to have some nice-formatted output. But when I use it, it simply doesn't print anything. In [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/616575/strange-format-list-behavior-in-this-powershell-script/701132) the author had the same problem. He was told not to call fl inside a function, but pipe the result back to main and output there.

Piping the results back to the caller sounds like a good idea, sure.

But what if functions are nested + already have a return value?

I want to output Certificate-Information for an sslstream. To do this, I have to use a custom Callback-Function for Validation. In this Callback-Function, the Certificate-Chain is available (and should be printed to screen). The Function is required to return $true

Simplified:

```
function write-CertDetails([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]$cert){
    #perform some conversions etc... e.g.:
    $certprops = new-object psobject
    $certprops | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FriendlyName" -Value $Cert.FriendlyName
    $certprops | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubjectName" -Value $Cert.SubjectName

    $certprops | fl #this does not work!
}

[System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback] $CertValCallback = {
param($sender, $certificate, $chain, $sslPolicyErrors)
    for($i = $chain.ChainElements.Count; $i-- -gt 0; ){
        write-CertDetails $currElement.Certificate
    }
    $true
}

# Create a TCP-Connection, open it in $tcpstream
Pseudo: $tcpstream = new-Object tcpConnection($host)
# now SSL/TLS-Handshake is performed. This calls the CertValCallback (which has to return true). New SslStream-Object is returned.
$sslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($tcpstream,$false,$CertValCallback)
```

I have no idea, how I should get the $certprops-Collection back to Main-Function...

Thanks for your Help

Filipp

Comment: Maybe you can return the `$certprops` object to a global variable inside write-certdetails. `[object[]]$global:certs += $certprops`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm this is tricky. I agree with the assertion that you should not use `Format-` cmdlets in functions, and should let the caller work with the objects.

But if the information is only available as a callback, you don't have control of the caller nor the function definition nor the parameters getting passed in so you can't really workaround much of this to get a value back to your code. So I'm assuming writing to the screen really is the only option here.

The reason piping the value to `fl` doesn't work in the function, is that the `Format-` cmdlets don't actually write anything to the screen. They merely format the output. Typically in a function those format objects get returned, and returned from whatever function called that function, and so on. Eventually if you're not in a function anymore, the objects are written to the screen by the host.

To see how this differs from explicitly writing to the host, consider `$v = $obj | Format-List` vs `$v = Write-Host $obj`. The latter will write `$obj` to the screen and `$v` will be empty/null. The former will output nothing to the screen and `$v` will contain the format object(s).

So to answer your question, you can try this:

```psh
$certprops | Format-List | Out-Host
```

That should force it out to the host without returning anything, so it won't mess with the callback's return value. `Write-Host` in this case wouldn't work because it would just display the class name.

Comment: Thank you briantist!

$certprops | Format-List | Out-Host

does just what I want to have.

I tested tons of different comandlets, pipes etc - but I never tested Out-Host (and $certprops | Format-List | write-host doesn't work, just like you described). Also thank you for your explanation regarding "Format-" cmdlets